# Cannot get delegated Jquery to work on Ajax loaded content

Tags: jquery, ajax

I having trouble figuring out how to delegate and trigger a jquery function on an AJAX-loaded piece of content. Here is my original HTML:

```
          <div class="container" id="toolOptions">
                            <div class="row" id="toolsrow">
                              <button onclick="loadDoc('url/to/Server', 'projectDataContent')> Click Me </button>
                            </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 currentToolsCol" id="projectdataColumn">
                                    <h2 class="viewHeader">Project Data</h2>
                                    <hr class="viewHeaderHR">
                                    <div id="projectDataContent">
        <!-- result.html dynamically loads here -->
           </div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-md-4 sliderContainer currentToolsCol" id="notesColumn">
                            <h2 class="sliderHeaderRow" id="notesHeader">Notes</h2>
                            <div class="appSliders" id="workspaceNoteSlider">
                                <i class="fa fa-book sliderMainbutton" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <h3 id="noteSliderHeader">View Project Notes</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="appSliderContent container-fluid " id="notesLoadZone" url='/serverURL /get/request/forNotes'>
                  Here is a note, should be hidden unless clicked
               </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3aed4d9ed5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I have an AJAX call, which is called on the click of a button in my application:

```
function loadDoc(myUrl, targetElemId) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(targetElemId).innerHTML =
                this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", myUrl, true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

This works fine, and dynamically loads the following View into the `#projectDataContent` area as expected:

`result.html`:

```
      <div class="container-fluid tableProcessingTools" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-10 sliderContainer">
                <h4 class="sliderHeaderRow" >Table Analysis Tools</h4>
                <div class="appSliders">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o tableProcessingIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>  <h5 class="processingDescription">Manually Add Row</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="appSliderContent container-fluid " url='#makeURLToAddRow'>
                    Form to manually add a row to this table here
                </div>
           </div> 
         </div>
      </div>
```

In both the originally loaded HTML, and the dynamically loaded in page, I have some `appSliders` which should start closed and open on a click. I mana

ge this with the following bit of jQuery, stored in an external element, and referenced internally:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.appSliderContent').hide();

    $('.appSliders').on('click', function () {
        var targetArea = $(this).next('.appSliderContent');
        var urlToPass = $(targetArea).attr('url');
        targetArea.load(urlToPass, function () {
                $(this).slideToggle()
            }
        );
    });
})
```

The `#workspaceNoteSlider` behaves correctly, starting closed, and popping open on a click. However, the dynamically loaded slider in `.tableProcessingTools` does not respond. The content starts in the open position, and does not respond on a click. First question is - shouldn't this work on its own?

My second question is why isn't delegation working? I have tried delegation where I attach a listener to an element which is present in the document prior to the AJAX call ( the `#projectDataContent` div) as such:

```
$('#projectDataContent').on("load", '.tableProcessingTools', function() {
    console.log(".tableProcessingTools has been loaded")
    $('.appSliderContent').hide();
    $('.appSliders').on('click', function () {
        console.log("caught the .appslider click")
        var targetArea = $(this).next('.appSliderContent');
        var urlToPass = $(targetArea).attr('url');
        targetArea.load(urlToPass, function () {
                $(this).slideToggle()
            }
        );
    });
});
```

But this doesn't register anything in the console. What am I doing wrong with the delegation on the AJAX - loaded content. I've read as many similar questions as possible, but they don't seem to work in my context. I want the Table Analysis Tools to behave like it is here in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pwnfy6t7/), but because it is dynamically loaded, it won't.

Comment: Several issues here. Firstly, there's no `#projectDataColumn` within the content you load in to `#projectDataContent` hence why the delegated event does nothing. In fact `#projectDataColumn` already exists in the DOM before the AJAX request *outside* of that element...? Secondly, `load` does not fire on `div` elements. What exactly do you want this code to do?

Comment: declare the `var that =$(this)`  then use the `that.slideToggle()` inside the load function

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)? You are also a bit confused about what delegation, with respect to DOM events, means. You would need to assign the `click` handler on a parent element, then filter for the correct element. E.g., `$(document).on('click', '.appSliders', function () { ... })`. See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for more detail.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  1. #projectDataColumn thing was a typo, should have been `.tableProcessingTools` . The desired event flow is : a.) On the button click, the `loadDoc(...)` AJAX call is fired, does a GET request on the server, and returns `result.html`, b.) loading it into the  ` #projectDataContent` div. c.) `result.html` has some sliders in it `.appSliderContent`, which, on load, should be hidden, but also respond to a click which will slide out and display itself.

Comment: In which case it would make more sense to use a `success` callback on the AJAX. See jQuery's documentation for more info http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

Comment: Basically I want the Table Analysis Tools box to behave like this - but it won't: https://jsfiddle.net/pwnfy6t7/

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, is `'#projectDataContent'` not a parent element? It is present at the original page load. And I'm unaware of what `$.ajax` or `$.load`
@RoryMcCrossan, apologies, but I've been in and out reading that documentation all day, but I'm not able to understand how to apply which piece of that to this context. Same goes with a callback, where would I attach that to? Could you provide a code example?

Comment: That element is not present in the DOM when you go to attach event handlers. You want something that is already there on load. In my example, I use `document` since of course it's always there. As @RoryMcCrossan already mentioned, there is no `load` event that fires on `div`s, so attach to the `click` event instead, as I showed in my example.

Comment: I'm confused , `'#projectDataContent'` is in the original DOM as indicated in the first chunk of original HTML, so it's present the whole time. But, I have tried as you have indicated, but ALL of the sliders open at the same time, rather than just the one clicked. And then they require a double click to open, and will open and close on their own a few times as well, very strange behavior. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/pwnfy6t7/1/  or this one too: https://jsfiddle.net/pwnfy6t7/2/

Comment: Also, shouldn't my first `$(document).ready(function () {` take care of the new sliders, even if they are added dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution using advice from the comments of Rory and Mike:

I used the callback portion of the original AJAX call to ensure the sliders were closed upon original load by doing this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.dataPickerIconDiv', function() {
    var targetArea = $(this).children("i");
    var urlToPass = $(targetArea).attr('url');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            $("#projectDataContent").prepend(this.responseText);
            $('.tptSliderContent').hide(); // hides the slider content of the table processing tools
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", urlToPass, true);
    xhttp.send();    
});
```

And then I was able to set the DOM to listen to an element that was present on the original page load. Instead of doing `document`, I did this one, so it would be more of a specific element:

```
$('#projectDataContent').on("click", '.tableProcessingToolSliders', function() {
        var targetArea = $(this).next('.tptSliderContent');
        targetArea.slideToggle();
});
```